# Perl map - need to map an array into a hash as arrayelement->array_index

Tags: perl, arrays, hash, mapping

I have a array like this:

```
my @arr = ("Field3","Field1","Field2","Field5","Field4");
```

Now i use map like below , where **/DOSOMETHING/** is the answer am seeking.

```
my %hash = map {$_ => **/DOSOMETHING/** } @arr
```

Now I require the hash to look like below:

```
Field3 => 0
Field1 => 1
Field2 => 2
Field5 => 3
Field4 => 4
```

Any help?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
%hash = map { $arr[$_] => $_ } 0..$#arr;

print Dumper(\%hash)
$VAR1 = {
          'Field4' => 4,
          'Field2' => 2,
          'Field5' => 3,
          'Field1' => 1,
          'Field3' => 0
        };
```

Answer (score 19):

```
my %hash;
@hash{@arr} = 0..$#arr;
```

Comment: It's a shame `%hash` has to be pre-declared, so we can't write something like `my @hash{@arr} = 0 .. $#arr;`...

Comment: @Zaid There are always cute tricks such as `@$_{@arr} = 0 .. $#arr for \my %hash;`, but eugene's code has less shock value.

Comment: @gbacon : Agreed, one shouldn't sacrifice readability for one-line-cramming. It's just that I would've imagined that Perl could auto-vivify with array slices as well.

Comment: @Zaid Your proposed syntax would be nice. You should send a patch to p5p!

Answer (score 2):

In Perl 5.12 and later you can use [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) on an array to iterate over its index/value pairs:

```
use 5.012;

my %hash;

while(my ($index, $value) = each @arr) {
    $hash{$value} = $index;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more way I can think of to accomplish this:

```
sub get_bumper {
    my $i = 0;
    sub { $i++ };
}

my $bump = get_bumper;         # $bump is a closure with its very own counter
map { $_ => $bump->(); } @arr;
```

As with many things that you *can* do in Perl: Don't do this.  :)  If the sequence of values you need to assign is more complex (e.g. 0, 1, 4, 9, 16... or a sequence of random numbers, or numbers read from a pipe), it's easy to adapt this approach to it, but it's generally even easier to just use [unbeli's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957903/47984).  The only advantage of this method is that it gives you a nice clean way to provide and consume arbitrary lazy sequences of numbers: a function that needs a caller-specified sequence of numbers can just take a coderef as a parameter, and call it repeatedly to get the numbers.

Comment: Why not just `my $i; my %hash = map { $_ => $i++ } @arr`

Comment: @eugeney: Yes, that's much simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

A very old question, but i had the same problem and this is my solution:

```
use feature ':5.10';

my @arr = ("Field3","Field1","Field2","Field5","Field4");
my %hash = map {state $i = 0; $_ => $i++} @arr;
```